# Virtual parent for containers and 'iterable' class

Tags: c++, inheritance, interface, iterator, std

I was wondering if there was a reason why there's no virtual parent inheritance for all std containers.

Since C++ is oop, I get some reason for using external function as such from algorithm header.

But i wonder why string does not have size() function ( doing the same as length ) for genericity?

Also, why is there no "iterable" class from which would iterables containers inherit ( because of the different types of iterator? )
This one come from my short experience with python. In my opinion, python's biggest strengh is how easy if is to use iterable.

EDIT:
To clarify myself: i know C++ is mutli-paradigm, but i would like to focus on containers. We could have keep C-style using struct and functions, why defining some as methods and others not? For encapsulation only?
Having both sequential and oop means is confusing and illogical i think
Why having begin(vec) and vec.begin() ?

And i speak about iterable, not iterators, and yes, iterator was a class in the std defining an iterface for iterator which is now deprecated ( and i understand why ). So iterators are object, why not doing iterable object ( juste to pack iterator begin and iterator end together if it is not to define virtual parent for iterable containers) ?

I hope i was clearer this time. I already got answer i thought about by myself for the most, but i would prefer an explanation about the current logic in the std.

Thank you for the time taken to read and answer.

Comment: `std::string` does have a [`size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size) member function.

Comment: _"C++ is oop"_ Where did you hear that?

Comment: There are three main reasons. Performance, performance and performance.

Comment: C++ has this "don't pay for what you don't use" principle.  
Having virtual size() methods would make stdvector's vtable bigger and its size() calls slower.

Comment: Sorry for string, i misses that. C++ is multi-paradigm, yeah. But here is the point of containers: they are done half oop, half C-style (algorithm function). Why? In that case we could have keep how it was in C ( because of the same reason why we won't add functions, ... in them ). I already thought about the answer i got up to now, and i agree, but why is the half made oop and the other not?

Answer (score 4):

> I was wondering if there was a reason why there's no virtual parent inheritance for all std containers.

There is a cost attached to this (virtual dispatch is not free!), and most people (all people?) wouldn't need it.

In C++, you don't pay for what you don't use. (In theory.)

> i wonder why string does not have size() function ( doing the same as length ) for genericity?

[It does.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size)

> why is there no "iterable" class from which would iterables containers inherit ( because of the different types of iterator? )

Because we don't need one. You claim that C++ is "oop", but that is not true: it is multi-paradigm, and most of the standard library (particularly the parts inherited from the antique STL) are *template* based, not object-oriented.

This allows us to provide iterators that fit a set of "requirements", rather than those that fit some definition of "class". For example, pointers (which do not have class type!) are a valid kind of iterator.

> This one come from my short experience with python. In my opinion, python's biggest strengh is how easy if is to use iterable.

That's reasonable. But C++ is not Python.

Comment: I took some times to rethink about it.
We already pay for some things we don't necessarily need (for example the iterators themselves) and C++ seems to be evolving to simplier code writing.
Having class inheritance would allow us to use polymorphism, benefit from code completions, have better readability on code... But i guess it would be to much to have available both kind of containers, and the less opinionated is probably the best.

If i need them i should create them myself, the same goes for python-like iterable object.

Thanks for the response

Answer (score 4):

> I was wondering if there was a reason why there's no virtual parent inheritance for all std containers.

Design decision at early stages of C++ standard forming. There is no much reason to do that - sure, you would have a nice common interface, but this can be also achieved with consistent standard managing (all containers already do have common set of functions without an explicit interface).
A disadvantage of a common base is that all containers would suddenly need virtual functions, and virtual functions are not free (more expensive at runtime than normal functions).

> Since C++ is oop

It's not. C++ is a multiparadigm language. For example, you can have functions outside of any class (unlike Java, which is following OOP paradigm more strictly).

> i get some reason for using external function as such from algorithm header.

A follow-up decision after the above. Having global functions accepting generic pair(s) of iterators allows to use any container (even user-defined) with these functions.

> But i wonder why string does not have size() function ( doing the same as length ) for genericity?

[It does have such a function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size) and it always had. `length()` is another option, provided for better readability - it's more "English" to ask about *length of string* than to ask about *size of string*

> Also, why is there no "iterable" class from which would iterables containers inherit ( because of the different types of iterator? ) This one come from my short experience with python. In my opinion, python's biggest strengh is how easy if is to use iterable.

There is one very good reason for that - **iterators don't have to be of class type**. Pointer type satisfies all of the requirements for [RandomAccessIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator), but it is not a class.

Comment: I know it is multi-paradigm, but doing classes and methods instead of C-style struct+functions ( like it is done with algorithm ) is not only for encapsulation, it is? So why going half way? I do not speak about ierators but iterable ( see in python ), and iterators are ( in most case ) objects. There was iterator in the std which defined a standard interface but it is now deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

C++ prefers compile-time polymorphism, suggesting you to use templates instead of virtual calls. Back in the good old days, it was more efficient (virtual calls are still not free).
There is however a certain level of standardization for containers: all of them support iterators, and standardized C++20 ranges are coming as well.

Comment: I know that it is not free, and we won't necessarly need it all, but my point is, and that's why i said C++ is oop:

Vectors have methods, we could have juste struct and function like how it was done in C. Is the only use of doing that the encapsulation?
Do you have an explanation for that?

Doing this way would mean defining methods, interface, polymorphism,... I am not really keen of the polymorphism, and i think it is good how it is, but that don't make sense, we could have stay with C style objects + functions with the explanation i got here.

Comment: Staying with C-style objects does not allow us to benefit from destructors, RAII and smart memory management. Encapsulation made it possible to implement high-level primitives in STL, boost and other libraries. It generally made the life of a C++ programmer much easier compared to a C programmer.

Comment: Constructor, desctructor (and RAII) was meant in the encapsulation. Memory management could be done through functions like in C and yes, because it is easier, BUT it would be easier for every function to be a method. Why do we use some element as functions and others as methods since they all share the same benefits and disavantage? It should be all or nothing or it should have a good reason

Comment: why should it be "all or nothing"? As it was mentioned by others, "c++ is not oop", c++ just supports oop as well as other paradigms.

Comment: As i said multiple time, i know it is multi-paradigm. All or nothing OR BOTH if it has a good reason. In this case, if you speak of "what you need only" or performance, why do we have methods and not functions like in C-style? On the other hand, if the response is "because it is convenient", then the free functions would be convenient too as methods. According to that, there is no visible reason to differentiate them, so it is all or nothing. If you have an explicit and reasonable reason/rule to say why it is or not a method, that is the answer i need